# CSS horizontal lines on wrapped <ul>

Tags: css, html-lists, word-wrap

I've got a list of items coming from a database:

```
<ul>
    <li>Jon Skeet</li>
    <li>Darin Dimitrov</li>
    <li>Marc Gravell</li>
    <li>BalusC</li>
    <li>Hans Passant</li>
    <li>SLaks</li>
    <li>VonC</li>
    <li>Greg Hewgill</li>
    <li>JaredPar</li>
</ul>
```

The list will wrap when necessary, and each line should have horizontal lines, and look a bit like this:

```
____________________________________________________
 Jon Skeet   Darin Dimitrov   Marc Gravell   BalusC
____________________________________________________
 Hans Passant   SLaks   VonC   Greg Hewgill
____________________________________________________
 JaredPar
____________________________________________________
```

However, I can't work out how to get the rows to have full-length lines, and so it looks like:

```
____________________________________________________
 Jon Skeet   Darin Dimitrov   Marc Gravell   BalusC
____________________________________________
 Hans Passant   SLaks   VonC   Greg Hewgill
__________
 JaredPar
__________
```

I've tried using `display:table-cell`, but I can't work out how to get them to wrap unless I know how many there should be in a row (which I don't).

I've [prepared a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LTbXN/3/) to illustrate how far I've got, and what it should look like. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're essentially trying to add a block level behavior to a group of inline elements. Is using a background image a possibility?

Comment: Well, let's say it is for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play around with repeating linear gradients - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LTbXN/33/)

```
ul, section {
    margin: 40px;
    max-width: 350px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;

    background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black 1px, white 1px, white 36px);
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(black 0, white 1px, white 36px);
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
​
```

Comment: +1 This is a nice solution, though it will struggle if the font-sizes change (as will any solution involving a repeating background)

Comment: Presumably you could use `em`s rather than `px`s for the last parameter to get round the font size?

Answer (score 0):

If inline-block doesn't do the trick, you could try `display: block` instead of `table-cell` and add some `float: left` property to keep everything on the same line.

You could play around with `clear: both` too. There are actually a lot of ways to do it, it depends on what you do prefer and if you want it to work on IE6 or any old cellphone...

Answer (score 0):

This one works with different font-sizes, or even with elements of different heights:

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    border: solid #000;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {

    padding: 5px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}

li:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    height: 1px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

This adds an absolute positioned full width line at the top of each element, and then hides the excess.